# Find and Replacing at the End of Line

Tags: replace, find, edit, text-editor, rich-text-editor

Say I have a document as follows:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

If I want the document to be:

```
abc,
def,
ghi,
```

Is there a way I can do it using `Find and Replace`. If not, is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example in notepad++ use replace with extended flag and replace '\r' by ',\r'

also if all lines has same length - you can select vertical area of end of lines by mouse and pressing Alt+Shift and type ','